# Purpose of php and php5 directories in /usr/share

Tags: php, linux

I have two directories in /usr/share named php and php5. One is not a symlink to the other. What is purpose of having these two directories. Is it to support multiple php versions to reside on the same machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look inside will tell you:

1. `/usr/share/php` is for actual .php scripts, as in installed PEAR packages.

   This directory is part of the [`include_path`](http://php.net/include_path)
2. `/usr/share/php5` contains the default .ini sections for installed modules. Therefore pretty much mirror `/etc/php5/*/conf.d`

   Courtesy of [php5-common](https://packages.debian.org/en/squeeze/php5-common) and dependend PECL extensions. For documentation on the packaging scheme and directory layout, have a look at https://wiki.debian.org/PHP or `/usr/share/doc/php5-common`.